# Aligning elements with grid and flex-box, CSS & Html

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to find a way to push the last row of the gird to the left so it doesn't stay centered but aligns with the grid.
Thanks for any help in advanced :)

image example bellow:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 77px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding-top: 114px;
  list-style-type: none;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#grid>div {
  border: solid 2px black;
  height: 208px;
  width: 370px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<section id="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: You should probably use flex for that, grids have rows and columns and you have to do ugly hacky stuff to escape that (hacky meaning hard to scale and maintain). with flex you just need to justify-content in the center

Comment: @arieljuod thanks for the reply :). How could I do that to make sure the flex stays centered and the gaps between the rows stay equal?

Comment: With grid, you usually want to control the width of the cells via the grid definition/grid container size. Why are you defining this on the cells instead? What exactly is your desired layout? Why are you assigning `1fr` to the columns? Why are you currently applying `justify-content: center`?

Comment: By the way, you have `display: grid;` then `display: flex;` so you are already using flexbox.

Comment: Also, there's quite a number of useless declarations on the #grid container like `flex-wrap` (which is only for `display: flex`) and `list-style-type: none` (which is only for list elements).

Comment: Why are you assigning `display: grid` only to make this declaration **totally useless** some lines later by overwriting it with `display: flex`?

Comment: Please take more care of your code example making sense before asking.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question (I thought you WANTED the last row centered like in the image), using grid is a perfect fit for that without any issue, your issue was actually using `display: flex`

Answer (score 0):

You are justifying to the center. You need to change that for `flex-start`.

```css
#grid {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

You can learn more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: hey, thanks it worked. And yeah sorry for the mistakes in the code, I'm pretty new to whole html and css scene.

Answer (score 0):

You override the `grid` property with a `display: flex`.

Without it, every block go the the left but the whole grid isn't centered anymore, to adjust that, you can add `justify-items: center`

Demo (I changed the block sizes to have a better preview)

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 77px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding-top: 114px;
  list-style-type: none;
  clear: both;
  /* display: flex; <-- HERE */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;

  /* new rule for centering */
  justify-items: center;

  /* preview */
  grid-gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

#grid>div {
  border: solid 2px black;
  height: 208px;
  width: 370px;
  justify-content: flex-start;

  /* preview */
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}

/* preview */
body { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<section id="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```